# Evaluating this integral $\int \frac{3x^2-1}{2x\sqrt{x}}\arctan(x){\rm d}x$, how to start?

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

I would like to evaluate $$\int \dfrac{3x^2-1}{2x\sqrt{x}}\arctan(x){\rm d}x$$ I'm not even sure how to start, any suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: Integration by parts might work... make the function you integrate $\frac{3x^2-1}{2x \sqrt{x}}$  and the other factor arctan(x) the one you differentiate.

Comment: WolframAlpha gives a very complex result.  Do you really have to perform this integral by hand?

Comment: @DavidG.Stork Are you sure you did not mistype? The one it told me was quite reasonable (id est approximately the same length as the integrand).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint**. Integration by parts is a nice route,
$$
\begin{align}
\int \dfrac{3x^2-1}{2x\sqrt{x}}\arctan(x){\rm d}x&=\int \left(\frac{3\sqrt{x}}{2}-\frac1{2x^{3/2}} \right)\arctan(x){\rm d}x
\\\\&=\left(x^{3/2}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}\right)\arctan(x)-\int \left(\frac{x^2+1}{\sqrt{x}} \right)\left(\arctan(x)\right)'{\rm d}x
\end{align}
$$ Can you finish it?

Comment: Absolutely! Thanks!!